# Self rotating screen

Tags: ubuntu, display

I'm using Ubuntu Linux and every hour or so (seems random) one of my two screens flips vertically for a few seconds and then turns back to normal. I tried reinstalling the nvidia drivers but it didn't help. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is periodic, so I would suggest you check your crontab entries. There might be a script in there, that could cause this problem.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be an office prank! There really was a script in crontab which sole purpose was to flip my screen every hour (with some random delay).

Comment: Gotta love office humor....  If they run macs make sure you get them back with a "say" loop :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add following to Craig Nelson's answer :

- You may try noting down the time for 2-3 instances. If there is a fixed time gap then there may be 2 issues :

--> There must be a script that will be executed by crond after every few hours OR
--> The script that executes the "messy" command is doing following :
1. Executes the command
2. sleep for some fixed interval 
3. Repeat step 1,2 many times

You should be able to check 2nd possibility by grepping of sleep from output of ps command.